# Dumping library assembly code for C

Tags: c, assembly

When I compile C program with GCC using -S switch, I get an assembly code for the C program I have written. But the generated assembly file sometimes contains code from libraries. For example

```
bl remainder
```

Is there a way to dump the code for library functions. In this case, is there a way to view the code for the library function `remainder`?

Comment: `objdump` the library?

Comment: If you run the program under a debugger, the debugger can usually disassemble specific functions. In gdb, for instance, you can type `disass remainder`. (This may only work after the program has been started, because of dynamic library loading).

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb to disassemble the library function, if you know its name or address (as Mark Plotnick suggests).  That'll at least give you some idea of what its code is.

However, a better answer is that when GCC invokes a function in a *standard* library, you should just go download the actual source code!  For certain operations, that source code may exist as part of the GCC distribution itself, and for others it may be part of glibc, but you're working with open-source software, so you have access to all the original code through the Internet.

I can't be sure exactly which architecture you're compiling to (looks like one of the ARM flavors?).  But either way, `remainder` is likely a builtin function that implements the `%` operator, so it came with GCC.  Simply searching the GCC Git repository for `remainder` and your CPU name should be able to find it.  (Here's where I'd start: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=remainder )